# What is the value of redirect_uri after authentication in a facebook page tab?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-apps

I am trying to setup a simple facebook page tab application. I have already reached the state where I get the access_token as a response from the facebook graph and seems to be correct. My problem is that after the authentication I get redirected to my facebook page tab url but *outside* the facebook domain and not in the page tab that the user has selected.

My application info:

```
    Display Name:MyContest
    Namespace:mygoodcontest
    Contact Email:myemail@something.com
    App Domains: [ empty ]

    Page Tab Name: Contest!
    Page Tab URL:http://[mystaticip]:8080/facebookContest/app/index.do
    Secure Page Tab URL:https://[mystaticip]:8443/facebookContest/app/index.do
    Page Tab Edit URL:https://[mystaticip]:8443/facebookContest/app/admin/
```

This thread seems to be exactly related to my problem and it seems to get answered irrelevantly.
[Redirect to Facebook page tab after authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973734/redirect-to-facebook-page-tab-after-authentication)

and this thread, is about the same problem that I am having, but on a canvas application. Not on a facebook page tab application
[Facebook canvas app "redirect_uri" breaks out of iframe after authorization & authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605265/facebook-canvas-app-redirect-uri-breaks-out-of-iframe-after-authorization-au)

What I am after, is to redirect the authenticated user inside the facebook page tab after the successful authorization.

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is in the same position as I was, here is what I managed to do with @darvex's help. The thing is that facebook needs the redirect_url param definitely. Also, the redirect_url param must be the same   with the page tab url in edit page options. So what I understood is that facebook redirects all users outside facebook (in this case "outside facebook" means your server , your page) then, you have to handle this http GET and as @darvex said, to redirect the request to your facebook page tab with a javascript command.

The magic happens when you redirect to your facebook page tab e.g. www.facebook.com/mypage/app_12345678 , the request comes to your handle because someone has requested your page tab. But, this time facebook has registered that this particular user has authenticated the app and thus, the http POST that is being processed at the time, has a signed_request param which if you break/decode(base64), you will find inside the access token that you need. At that point, you have a logged in user looking at your page tab - inside facebook- and an access token to do your tricks.

I don't know if this is the best practice, but seems to work. Please if anyone has a better approach feel free to post it.

thank you all

Answer (score 0):

When authenticating user, you can pass `redirect_uri` parameter with URL where you want to redirect user. You could try entering your tab's url there. If that won't work (probably because you'll get error saying that uri doesn't belong to your app), you could simply make a redirect from your page outside the Facebook to your tab.

Comment: hi Darvex, when you say the tab url you mean something like 
http://www.facebook.com/mytestPage/app_[APPID]  ?

Comment: Well this is the expected error:
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: The application parameters prohibit the specified url address

Is it a general practice to redirect from your page back to facebook? Not to offend by any means, but it seems weird though.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't say if it's the right way or not, but that's the way you will usually find. Not to mention all of the page tabs i've created were supposed not to be available via the full link (the one you leave in "page tab url")

Comment: I am really sorry but I cant figure out what you mean by " Not to mention all of the page tabs i've created were supposed not to be available via the full link (the one you leave in "page tab url") ". If I convert the application to a facebook canvas application would it be correct? In general...should it be so difficult to authenticate a user in a facebook page tab?

Comment: By that i meant that my page is not supposed to be accessible outside the Facebook. Authenticating user isn't hard, depending on what you need to know about user, you might not even need to do anything. Signed_request (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/) contains information like whether or not user has liked your page

Comment: I do understand your point @Darvex, but the issue is about a very general flow. As described below, Click a facebook page tab -> authenticate/grant permissions -if not already authenticated- -> enter the facebook page tab having access_token. I am trying to find an answer on how to get to the facebook page tab after authenticating. Until now the answers are a bit vague, although the matter has been discussed thoroughly. Maybe I have missed something in the documentation. Please feel free to post if you have a link. Thank you for your time,
Stefan